# Stencil @Element not finding child node

Tags: stenciljs

I have web component where i am trying to select a child node via the @Element property:

`` export class StepupVerification {
  @Prop() token: string = 'test';
  @State() url: string = `http://localhost:8080/?fail=${this.token}`;
  @Element() private element: HTMLElement;
... ``

however, The query selector I am using on the item is returning zero children when I know the element exists. I know because I can find it with the same selector off of document.

Here is the selector I am using:

`this.element.querySelectorAll('.stepup-frame');`

as I said, it returns zero elements. however when I use:

`document.querySelectorAll('.stepup-frame');`

I am finding the element fine.

**TL;DR:** querySelector on an element is not working correctly for my webcomponent, and I am not sure why.

Comment: Where did you put the querySelectorAll query? Only after the component is being  rendered you will be able to query elements using the host element (@Element). Also, if the component includes a slot then this is a different case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was really looking to use the ref functionality to get references to embedded elements.

i was able to add a `private myElement: HTMLElement` variable to my component, and then reference it via `this.myElement` within my code.

Comment: You can use the ref option in Stencil. I even wrote about it (https://medium.com/@gilfink/using-refs-in-stencil-3a709467f5c7).